# Problems with PayPal in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I have correctly configured payments with PayPal in WooCommerce, sometimes I get orders and pay for PayPal and everything is fine, but sometimes some customers pay and WooCommerce does not change the status of the order to "Paid", and for that reason customers contact me to tell me that they already paid and yes.

Does anyone feel the same?

PS: This error is occasional, I do not know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just log in to your PayPal account and see if the transactions that show an incorrect status in WooCommerce do actually exist in your PayPal transaction log with the correct status. If so, then you should contact WooCommerce support for them to explain why those same transactions do not show up with the correct status in their portal. If WooCommerce tells you that it's an issue with PayPal (and thus, there is nothing to be corrected at their side), then open a case with PayPal support and they can look into the logs being sent from WooCommerce's API calls into PayPal to confirm whether or not they are doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Standard that comes with WooCommerce uses IPN to update the order status.  Unfortunately, their IPN integration is not great, and it often fails.

If you use my [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/) instead, and setup Express Checkout, this problem will not happen.  Also, you'll have a lot more features and functionality.